# PythonのDictionary多次元化

Tags: python, django

以下のようにDictionaryを変換して多次元化するコードを書きたいのですが、可読性と速度の良いコードについてアドバイスいただけないでしょうか。

```
before_dict = {
    'Book' : 'Wood',
    'Chapter--1' : 'Leaves',
    'Chapter--2' : 'Branches',
    'Chapter--3' : 'Trunk',
    'Section--1--Chapter' : 1,
    'Section--1--Title' : 'Green',
    'Section--2--Chapter' : 1,
    'Section--2--Title' : 'Russet',
}
```

変換後は以下のような多次元にしたいと思います。

```
after_dict = {
    'Book' : 'Wood',
    'Chapter' : {'1' : 'Leaves', '2' : 'Branches', '3' : 'Trunk'}
    'Section' : {
        '1' : { 'Chapter' : '1', 'Title' : 'Green' },
        '2' : { 'Chapter' : '2', 'Title' : 'Russet' }
    }
}
```

CakePHPからDjangoに乗り換えたのですが、CakePHPでは
<input name="var[chapter][1]" ...>
のようにビューを作ると、コントローラで受け取ったPOSTデータも多次元配列になっていたので
困らなかったのですが、Djangoではこれが手動でやるしかないのかと悩みながらの質問です。

よろしくお願いします。

=== 追記 ===
自分でやってみて、こんな風に書けば4階層までは希望通り動いたのですが・・・あまりにもかっこ悪いのでどうにかしたいと思っています。

```
after_dict={}

for key,val in before_dict.items():

    key2 = key.split('--')

    if len(key2)==1:
        after_dict[key2[0]] = val

    elif len(key2)==2:
        if(after_dict.get(key2[0])==None):
            after_dict[key2[0]] = {}
        after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]] = val

    elif len(key2)==3:
        if(after_dict.get(key2[0])==None):
            after_dict[key2[0]] = {}
            after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]] = {}
        if(after_dict.get(key2[0]).get(key2[1])==None):
            after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]] = {}
        after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]][key2[2]] = val

    elif len(key2)==4:
        if(after_dict.get(key2[0])==None):
            after_dict[key2[0]] = {}
            after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]] = {}
            after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]][key2[2]] = {}
        if(after_dict.get(key2[0]).get(key2[1])==None):
            after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]] = {}
            after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]][key2[2]] = {}
        if(after_dict.get(key2[0]).get(key2[1]).get(key2[2])==None):
            after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]][key2[2]] = {}
        after_dict[key2[0]][key2[1]][key2[2]][key2[3]] = val
```

Comment: 発生し得るデータのパターンや組み合わせは質問に書かれたものが全てでしょうか？ もっと多様なデータがあるとか何か組み合わせの法則が判っている場合は、それを追記してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問にあいまいな点がありすいません。組み合わせの法則についてはすべて例なので、キーなどはどんな文字列が来るかわからない前提でお願いします。また、"--"で区切られる配列の深さはMAX6階層程度で十分と考えています。

Comment: ソフトウェアを設計・製作する上では「キーなどはどんな文字列が来るかわからない前提」とか「程度で十分」といった曖昧な言葉や定義は、解釈の違いや問題発生の原因になるので避けてください。仕様を考える際には全ての場合を想定して記述し、それを最小限のルールで処理出来るように条件を限定したり法則を考えたりする必要があります。そうで無いと質問のソースコードように、あまり整理されていない意味の良く分からない固定数値や階層指定が山のように出てきたり、似たようでいて少し違う処理が繰り返し行われることになります。分類的なキーワード('Book','Chapter','Section','Title')と序数('1','2','3')の種類と`キーワード--序数`の並び方や繰り返し方とか、途中まで同じ並び('Section--1--...')のものは連続した行にあること等を仮にでも決めておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ちなみに古いですがこんな記事があるようです。[Django, Python: Is there a simple way to convert PHP-style bracketed POST keys to multidimensional dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1890013/9014308), [Convert PHP array to a string in Python dictionary format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8935491/9014308) 何か参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: @kunif アドバイスありがとうございます。フロントエンドをSPA的に作ればJSONもありうるのでいただいたリンクの内容などはそういう場合には役に立ちそうです。時間を節約したいので今回はFormからのPOSTリクエストを利用して、@oririさんの回答を利用することとさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

再帰関数を使った方法
(元の dictの値に数値が入ってるのを, 文字列変換するなら以下の通り)

```py
def fn(d, ks, v):
    k = ks[0]
    if len(ks) == 1:
        d[k] = str(v)   # 文字列へ変換する場合
        #d[k] = v   # 値そのまま使用する場合
    else:
        sdict = d.setdefault(k, {})
        fn(sdict, ks[1:], v)

after_dict = {}
for k,v in before_dict.items():
    fn(after_dict, k.split('--'), v)
```

---

【追記】
`if dct.get(key) == None:` のような条件判断は

- `None`, `True`, `False` などとの比較判定には `v is None` などのように `is` を使うほうがよい (比較的わかりやすい ＆ 高速) (但し `v is True` は**場合によっては** `v` のみがよいかも)
- `key`に対する値が `None`もあり得る場合 これでは判定できないので `key in dct` や `key not in dct` が望ましい

Comment: 再帰関数の発想はあったものの、こう実装すればできたのですね。助かりました、ありがとうございます。